# MemoryError tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, p2

I'm running this model from AWS instance of type P2.xlarge. It is giving an error as:

```
Exception in thread Thread-16:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/models/summarization/textsum/batch_reader.py" , line 136, in _FillInputQueue
(article, abstract) = input_gen.next()
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/models/summarization/textsum/batch_reader.py", line 245, in _TextGenerator
e = example_gen.next()
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/models/summarization/textsum/data.py", line 109, in ExampleGen
example_str = struct.unpack('%ds' % str_len, reader.read(str_len))[0]
MemoryError
```

System storage info is -

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev 30G 0 30G 0% /dev
tmpfs 6.0G 8.9M 6.0G 1% /run
/dev/xvda1 30G 12G 18G 39% /
tmpfs 30G 0 30G 0% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
tmpfs 30G 0 30G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs 6.0G 0 6.0G 0% /run/user/1000
```

NVIDIA status-

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-161:~$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

00:1e.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev a1)

What is the solution for this?

If I replace `str_len = struct.unpack('q', len_bytes)[0]` with `str_len = struct.unpack('Bi', len_bytes)[0]`
then this error disappears and new error come up as:

```
Exception in thread Thread-15:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/mindstix/bazel/models/Summarizer/textsum/batch_reader.py", line 136, in _FillInputQueue
(article, abstract) = input_gen.next()
File "/home/mindstix/bazel/models/Summarizer/textsum/batch_reader.py", line 248, in _TextGenerator
article_text = self._GetExFeatureText(e, self._article_key)
File "/home/mindstix/bazel/models/Summarizer/textsum/batch_reader.py", line 265, in _GetExFeatureText
return ex.features.feature[key].bytes_list.value[0]
IndexError: list index (0) out of range
```

If I print `example_str` then the value displays on screen. But when I try to print `ex.features.feature[key].bytes_list.value` it returns blank.

what should be done to resolve all this?

This is the code steps I am following:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> import struct
>>>from tensorflow.core.example import example_pb2
>>> reader = open('data/training-1', 'rb')
>>> len_bytes = reader.read(8)
>>> str_len = struct.unpack('q', len_bytes)[0]
>>> str_len
2335523720558635124
>>> example_str = struct.unpack('%ds' % str_len, reader.read(str_len))[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError

>>> str_len = struct.unpack('Bi', len_bytes)[0]
>>> str_len
116

>>> example_str = struct.unpack('%ds' % str_len, reader.read(str_len))[0]
>>>e = example_pb2.Example.FromString(example_str)
>>> e.features.feature['article'].bytes_list.value
<google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer object at  0x7fc25c9325a8>

>>> e.features.feature['article'].bytes_list.value[0] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index (0) out of range
```

Comment: Hard to say anything without the rest of the code as context. Could you condense that into a minimal but runnable example?

Comment: @AllenLavoie I had updated the question with the sample code which I am trying to run using tensorflow.

Comment: So the article feature is empty? Is there a reason to think it shouldn't be? It might be useful to just print the whole example (`print(e)`) to see what gets parsed. Also not sure what's going on with the `struct` usage: maybe [TFRecord](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/python_io) format would be a more stable storage format?

Comment: Can you please tell me that, What will be the better approach to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I got stacked with the same problem. But the reason is that I use the raw text file for test. It is the transferred binary file should be used. I'm not sure whether your situation is the same with me.

Comment: My error was resolved. That error was because of incorrectness in binary format of input file to tensorflow/textsum.
`example_str = struct.unpack('%ds' % str_len, reader.read(str_len))[0]` 
read() function need value to read that bytes of data. and I was passing invalid size.  thus resultantly
`e.features.feature['article'].bytes_list.value` is having nothing. The object was blank at that time.
I tried to convert text format to tensorflow acceptable format.
using [https://github.com/surmenok/TextSum/blob/master/textsum_data_convert.py].

Comment: @LeenaBharambe Can you provide any help coz I'm referring the same code and got stuck at the same line. thanks in advance